# Calculating if Start time occurs within 1 hour range for each person (Single column)

Tags: sas

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate if start time for each subject occurs within 1 hour of each other. However I only have one column and two groups with two different dates for each. I have no comparative variable to a dhms time difference as they occur under the same column variable. I have thought of doing a lag on the first time and then an intchk to calculate the 24 hour time difference between each but I don't think i have sufficient arguments for the intchk function. Alternatively could maybe do a proc transpose and then do a timediff between each array variable but that seems messy. Anyone have less clunky and more efficient solutions as i might be overthinking this.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ262.png):

```
+----------+-------+------+------------+------------+
| CLIENTID | GRPID | date | start_date | start_time |
+----------+-------+------+------------+------------+
|        2 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:19:52   |
|        3 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:22:51   |
|        4 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:20:16   |
|        5 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:21:30   |
|        6 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:23:51   |
|       23 |     2 |   -2 | 11Nov2019  | 23:11:38   |
|       24 |     2 |   -2 | 11Nov2019  | 23:38:33   |
|       25 |     2 |   -2 | 11Nov2019  | 23:15:01   |
|       26 |     2 |   -2 | 11Nov2019  | 23:08:43   |
+----------+-------+------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: What would the expected results be? Are you trying to do this once per dataset or once per GRPID in the dataset? Can the times ever span midnight and still be within an hour of each other, as 00:01 being within an hour of 23:19 (requiring both the date and time columns to be checked)? Have you considered checking the min and max against each other?

Comment: I think what is required is to use the 1st start time as a baseline and then every other timepoint cannot be +/- hour from that time point. So ideally i would just a 24 hour calculation of each start time per clientid. So if there was a differenc column adjacent to start time it would be blank for client 2 and then 00:02:59 for clientid 3, 00:01:24 for clientid 4 etc if that makes sense. That's why I thought a lag function would work here.

Comment: You think? You're not sure about your own requirements?

Comment: Yes that is my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile the start date and time into a temporary datetime variable (`_start_dt`) to ease the comparison.  Then, taking the first datetime for each GRPID as the baseline, you could use a `RETAIN` statement to pass that baseline datetime (`_base_dt`) down the related data rows and find the time difference (`time_diff`) using the `INTCK` function with a `dtsecond` interval.

```
proc sort data=your_data;
    by grpid clientid;
run;

data your_results (drop=_:);
    retain CLIENTID GRPID DATE start_date start_time _base_dt;
    format _base_dt _start_dt datetime16. time_diff time8.;
    set your_data;
    by grpid clientid;
    _start_dt = dhms(start_date,hour(start_time),minute(start_time),second(start_time));
    if first.grpid then _base_dt = _start_dt;
    time_diff = intck('dtsecond', _base_dt, _start_dt);
run;
```

This gives the following results dataset:

```
+----------+-------+------+------------+------------+-----------+
| CLIENTID | GRPID | date | start_date | start_time | time_diff |
+----------+-------+------+------------+------------+-----------+
|        2 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:19:52   | 00:00:00  |
|        3 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:22:51   | 00:02:59  |
|        4 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:20:16   | 00:00:24  |
|        5 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:21:30   | 00:01:38  |
|        6 |     1 |   -2 | 10Nov2019  | 23:23:51   | 00:03:59  |
|       23 |     2 |   -2 | 11Nov2019  | 23:11:38   | 00:00:00  |
|       24 |     2 |   -2 | 11Nov2019  | 23:38:33   | 00:26:55  |
|       25 |     2 |   -2 | 11Nov2019  | 23:15:01   | 00:03:23  |
|       26 |     2 |   -2 | 11Nov2019  | 23:08:43   | -0:02:55  |
+----------+-------+------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

I *think* I’ve interpreted your requirements correctly..  Let me know if not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check if the `RANGE` of the `start_time` over each `group` is `< 1 hour`:

Coerce the `start_date` to a datetime value and add the `start_time` before computing the range.

```
data have;
input 
CLIENTID  GRPID  date  start_date: date9. start_time: hhmmss6.;
format start_date date9. start_time time8.;
datalines;
 2      1    -2  10Nov2019   23:19:52   
 3      1    -2  10Nov2019   23:22:51   
 4      1    -2  10Nov2019   23:20:16   
 5      1    -2  10Nov2019   23:21:30   
 6      1    -2  10Nov2019   23:23:51   
23      2    -2  11Nov2019   23:11:38   
24      2    -2  11Nov2019   23:38:33   
25      2    -2  11Nov2019   23:15:01   
26      2    -2  11Nov2019   23:08:43   
run;

proc sql;
  create table want (label="start range status by group") as
  select 
    grpid,
    range(dhms(start_date,0,0,0)+start_time) as start_range format time8.,
    calculated start_range < '24:00:00't as one_hr_start_flag
  from have
  group by grpid;
```

If you want to disregard the groups and focus only on the *time of day*, disregarding the date, the range computation would be:

```
* Presuming 'noon' is the center of the day;
proc sql;
  create table want (label="time of day start range status overall") as
  select 
    range(start_time) as range format time8.,
    calculated range < '24:00:00't as one_hr_start_flag
  from have;
```

Looking at only time is always troublesome for the cases of when the time value is slightly after midnight.